# Hamburger button must be clicked twice to expand

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrolling one-page website that has had some problems. The hamburger menu must be clicked twice in order to expand. I’m not very familiar with javascript but am wondering if something can be added to my existing javascript to solve the problem.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
   $('#menu').slideToggle();
  });
 $('#show-menu').change(function() {
  if(this.checked)
   $('#menu').slideDown();
  else
   $('#menu').slideUp();
  });
 });
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {

 nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */ }

 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  float: none; }

 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

 nav ul li:nth-of-type(1) { margin-top: 20%; }

 nav ul li:hover { background: #565758; }
 
 /*Style that thing pretty*/
 nav ul li a {
  color: white !important;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  display: inline-block; }

 nav ul li a.active-link {
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 1.3em; }

 nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  width: 100%; }
  
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 1em !important;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  float: right; }

 /*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu { background-color: #747475 !important; display: block; height: 100vh; }
}
​
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <nav>
   <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><img src="hamburger.png" alt="Hamburger Menu Icon" style="width: 15%;"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu" class="open">
      <li><a href="#choco">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-page">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio-page">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>​
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: What do you mean by clicked twice? Like a double click or a 3 part toggle?

Comment: works fine for me too

Comment: Thank you, everybody. Thank you, KolaCaine but this code is not working on my page (probably because I'm not putting the code in the right places). I'm sadly lacking in javascript knowledge. OfficialAntarctica, by click twice I mean a double click with the mouse on the hamburger icon. That is what it takes to expand the menu, which is a full-screen menu.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
var click = document.querySelector(".menu");
var content = document.querySelector(".content");

click.addEventListener("click", function(){
  content.classList.toggle("toggle");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: beige;
  transition: .5s;

}
.toggle {
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Click</div>
<div class="content toggle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;
$("#id").click(function() {
count++;
var isEven = function(someNumber) {
 return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
};
if (isEven(count) === false) {
alert("test1");
} else if (isEven(count) === true) {
 alert("test2");
}
});
});
```

here's the sample of double click, you can use it.

Comment: Thank you, Myco Claro. I'll keep this for the next time I run into this problem.

Comment: okay if it's helpful for you. please don't forget to click helpful button :) thanks! <3

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for my page. Please excuse me if I didn't set it up in the right form. I adapted this javascript from an answer to another poster's question that was very like mine. The solution came from Joseph Marikle.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
  })
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav li a').click(function(){
   $('#show-menu').trigger('click');
  })
   })
 })
```